# How to achieve animations just like gmail app?

Tags: android, android-animation

When click on button_next then linear_layout_email slide left and linear_layout_password will come from right. example https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqHAb.jpg

Here my java code paste below. please find some solution on it.

```
mLinearLayoutEmail.animate().translationX(-1000);
mLinearLayoutPassword.animate().translationX(-80);
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure of the animation you mean. Is there any chance you could add a video or gif or further explanation to your question?

Comment: please go through gmail app in android. when you put email address and click next then first screen slide to left and next scree i.e password screen comes from right.

Comment: Use slide_in_out animations on view; link below
http://deepaknenmini.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=4180&ownerUserId=deepak

Answer (score 0):

To me its better to read all the animation calculate them and then go for making Xml anim for each of the anim and use it as you need using AnimationUtils!

here its done in step by step! there is a builtin method for animation.

follow the steps in the code!

FADE IN RIGHT
[![FADE IN RIGHT animation in xml anim file][1]][1]

slide left
[![ANim xml code for slide and fade left][2]][2]

using ANimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,ANimFileResource) to read the anim file

e.g

```
Animation FadeAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fading_anim);
```

use StartAnimation method over the linearLayout in the ClickListener of the button you want to use for loading the anim  for example

```
fabPostTimeLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                mGetSwipedLeftLinLay.startAnimation(FadeAnim);
                }
        });
```

Comment: dude its is not about startActivity.....u didnt get my question... i am looking for animation between two linear layout.

Comment: please see the animation in above link....when click next the first layout slides to left and next layout comes form right.